# How do I write a function that can access any element of a Vec2s inside of a vector<Vec2s>

Tags: c++, opencv

I was hoping someone could show me how to write a function that can access any element of any Vec*, eg Vec2s*, Vec2b*, inside of  a vector_Vec2s*. vector_Vec2s* is a typedef for `vector<Vec2s>.`

here is my attempt so far(I'm still learning), so if the first Vec2s in the vector_Vec2s* had elements [1,2] I would like to be able to return either the 1 or the 2

```
 short std_vector_get_element( vector_Vec2s* v, int i ) {
 vector_Vec2s v = *v; 
 int a = v[i];
 return a;
 }
```

Comment: don't you need 2 indices, one for the vector , one for the Vec2 ? v[i] is a Vec2, not an int. v[i][0] would be 1, v[i][1] would be 2

Comment: **1)** why do you call by pointer and not by reference? **2)** Why do you make a copy of the argument if you don't really use it? **3)** what is `Vec2s`? For your code to compile it has to be convertible to `int`, but your explanation suggests it is something more. You should try to provide more information, e.g. a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to clarify your problem.

Comment: @ArneMertz answering (3), `typedef Vec<short, 2> Vec2s;`, where [**`Vec`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec) is a fundamental template in OpenCV.

Comment: And finally, why do you need a macro when a function will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `vector_Vec2s` is a vector of vectors, then you should say to your function (or macro) index of element of **which** vector do you want to get. As I see the function should be like this:

```
short std_vector_get_element( vector_Vec2s * v
                            , unsigned int vectorIdx
                            , unsigned int elementIdx ) {
    return (*v)[ vectorIdx ][ elementIdx ];
}
```

or macro

```
#define std_vector_get_element( v, vectorIdx, elementIdx ) \
    (*v)[ vectorIdx ][ elementIdx ]
```

or better like this

```
template< class T >
T std_vector_get_element( const std::vector< std::vector< T > > & v
                        , unsigned int vectorIdx
                        , unsigned int elementIdx ) {
    return v[ vectorIdx ][ elementIdx ];
}
```

but in this case I can't see any reason to have this function instead of writing just this:

```
short elem = v[ vectorIdx ][ elementIdx ]; // I think this is better then the next
//short elem = std_vector_get_element( v, vectorIdx, elementIdx );
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your code:

```
 short std_vector_get_element( vector_Vec2s* v, int i ) {
 vector_Vec2s v = *v; 
 int a = v[i];
 return a;
 }
```

- Result type `short`:
  Just use `int` when there is no very good reason to use anything else. Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil.
- Name `std_vector_get_element` with type indication:
  In C++ functions can be and often are overloaded on argument types. Most often there is no need to indicate an argument type in the name. On the other hand, indicating a result type can often be a good idea. Note also that `operator()` is a valid name for a member function, and supports pretty natural notation for indexing. One convention for an alphabetic name, established by `std::vector`, is to call it `at`, and `item` isn't a bad name either.
- Argument type `vector_Vec2s *`:
  First of all the formal argument should be `const`, so that the function can be used for `const` actual argument. Secondly the argument type should be a reference, not a pointer, e.g. in order to be able to pass a function result directly as actual argument, and to avoid the uncertainty associated with whether a pointer is 0 or not. So, use argument type `vector_Vec2s const&`.
- Argument type `int` for the index:
  This is ordinarily OK, but not if you want to support >4G items on a 64-bit platform. In that case use `ptrdiff_t` from `<stddef.h>`, which also is a signed type (it's the type of a pointer difference).
- Copying `vector_Vec2s v = *v;`:
  Such copying is unnecessary and just an added inefficiency.

Then for the original code we're down to …

```
 int item( int const i, vector_Vec2s const& v )
 {
     return v[i];
 }
```

Hopefully this will help you with your task of “how to write a function that can access any element of any Vec*”, which I find a bit too unclear to address.

Comment: v[i] is a Vec2s, not an int

Comment: @berak: look at the OP's code. `v[i]` is claimed to be assignable to `int`, by way of assigning it to `int`.